No instances created on cluster (even though min capacity=1)
I am trying to create a ECS cluster (fib-cluster-10) with min 1 instance, using the following settings under "infrastructure":

the ecsInstanceRole has the following policy JSON:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeTags",
                "ecs:CreateCluster",
                "ecs:DeregisterContainerInstance",
                "ecs:DiscoverPollEndpoint",
                "ecs:Poll",
                "ecs:RegisterContainerInstance",
                "ecs:StartTelemetrySession",
                "ecs:UpdateContainerInstancesState",
                "ecs:Submit*",
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ecs:TagResource",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ecs:CreateAction": [
                        "CreateCluster",
                        "RegisterContainerInstance"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

I've created a VPC with 2 private subnets, 2 public subnets
(and a security group to allow all TCP on the private subnets).
When creating the cluster, I select the private subnets:

(the other optional stuff I left out).
When I hit create, I get 0 instances associated to the cluster:

(when I then try and deploy a TaskDefinition using a service, I get error saying my cluster has no instances)

Did you check in the EC2 console if the instances are being created, and they are just unable to connect to the cluster? From your network description, it sounds like you may not have a NAT Gateway, or the appropriate VPC endpoints, required to allow EC2 instances in a private subnet to register with the ECS cluster.

Thanks a lot Mark B, that was the issue - didn't have Route Table entries linking private subnets to to public ones via the NAT gateway. This isn't very obvious (wish there was a aws article just going through this stuff, also how to set up ALB with ASG and target groups as it's a complex setup)
Can see the instances now!

